# Using ant and hibernate envers to create audity tables

Tags: hibernate, ant, hibernate-envers

I am newer with Hibernate Envers and I trying to generate audity tables, without success :(... I am using `hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar` and `hibernate-envers-3.5.6-Final.jar`.

My first attempt was to create directly audity tables setting `hbm2ddl.auto` property to `update` in my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
...
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete">org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener</property>
    <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate">org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListene</property>
...
 </session-factory>
```

And my audited classes are like following:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "EAL_USUS_USUARIOS", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
    "BIC_ENTIDAD", "ID_INTERNO_ENTIDAD" }))
public class EalUsusUsuarios implements java.io.Serializable {
```

But the update command ignores audity tables, so I tried creating an ant task to generate a schema ddl file, so in my `build.xml` file there is a task like:

```
<target name="schemaexport" description="Exports a generated schema to DB and file">
    <echo message="generación schema "/>
  <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask"
    classpath="${CK_JARS}/hibernate-envers-3.5.6-Final.jar"/>
 <hibernatetool destdir="${clases.dir}">
    <classpath>
      <fileset refid="hibernate-envers-3.5.6-Final.jar" />
      <path location="${CK_JARS}/" />
    </classpath>
    <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="ConsolePU" />
    <hbm2ddl
      drop="false"
      create="true"
      export="false"
      outputfilename="C:/Desarrollo/versioning-ddl.sql"
      delimiter=";"
      format="true"/>
  </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

This configuration is obviously not working and is because I am not sure what values should be setted in classpath. I though that was the directory where  envers jar is located but I got a "taskdef A class needed by class `org.hibernate.tool.ant.EnversHibernateToolTask` cannot be found: `org/hibernate/tool/ant/HibernateToolTask`" error message from ant console.

Any idea about where is the problem in any of both ways?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer myself and ,hopefully, try to be hepfull for others.

First off all, I almost went mad triying to configure my `hibernate.cfg.xml` in order to be able to use envers. Finally I gave up this option and I migrate to JPA 2.0. For setting up jpa configuration, is necessary to have a `persistence.xml`in your `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` directory. In my case, this archive seems like follows:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence             
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="****" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/EaliaPagosDTSource</jta-data-source>
<class>es.cecabank.ealiapagos.accesobd.model.EalUsusMediospEsts</class>
<class>es.cecabank.ealiapagos.accesobd.model.EalUsusAliasEsts</class> 
...
<properties>
    <!-- property name="javax.persistence.transactionType"
   value="RESOURCE_LOCAL" /-->
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="false"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:********"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="****"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.default_schema" value="****"/>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
    <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Notice that I am setting JTA in configuration for transation-type. This is quite important since the way you manage transactions depends on this value. In my case, I use transactions with a Datasource defined in `<jta-data-source>`tag, wich refers to a Datasource declared in JBOSS configuration file `standalone.xml`. I marked my entities with @Audited annotation and audit tables were automaticallye generated in the moment I deployed my app in JBOSS 7.1

If any one needs more details, don't hesitate to ask